# Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This question has been posted before. I want to verify my solution.

$f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ be a continuously differentiable function s.t $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

Prove that exists a point $c\in (a,b)$ such that

$\left|f'(c)\right| \geq \frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_{a}^bf(x)dx$

**SOLUTION**

Let $G(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$

$G(a)=0$

$G(b)=\int_a^bf(t)dt$

By LMVT on $y=G(x)$ for $\left(a,b\right)$

$G'(d)=\frac{G(b)-G(a)}{b-a}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(t)dt$ ,where $a<d<b$

Similarly,by LMVT on  $y=f(x)$ for $\left( a,d\right)$

$f'(c_{1})=\frac{f(d)-f(a)}{d-a}= \frac{\frac{\int_a^bf(t)dt}{b-a}-0}{d-a}=\frac{1}{(b-a)(d-a)}\int_a^bf(t)dt$,where $a<c_{1}<d<b$

Similarly,by LMVT on  $y=f(x)$ for $\left( d,b\right)$

$f'(c_{2})=\frac{f(b)-f(d)}{b-d}= \frac{0-\frac{\int_a^bf(t)dt}{b-a}}{b-d}=-\frac{1}{(b-a)(b-d)}\int_a^bf(t)dt$,where $a<d<c_{2}<b$

Since $f'(x)$ is given to be continuous so there must exist at least one $x=c$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f'(c_{1})+f'(c_{2})}{2}$

$f'(c)=\left(\frac{1}{d-a}-\frac{1}{b-d}\right)\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(t)dt$

$f'(c)=\frac{2}{(b-a)}\frac{\frac{a+b}{2}-d}{(d-a)(b-d)}\int_a^b f(t)dt$

$\left|f'(c)\right|=\left|\frac{2}{(b-a)}\frac{\frac{a+b}{2}-d}{(d-a)(b-d)}\int_a^b f(t)dt\right|$

$\left|f'(c)\right|=\frac{2}{(b-a)}\frac{1}{(d-a)(b-d)} \left| \left(\frac{a+b}{2}-d\right)\int_a^b f(t)dt\right|$

$\left|f'(c)\right|\geq\frac{2}{(b-a)}\frac{1}{(d-a)}\frac{1}{(b-d)} \left| \frac{a+b}{2}-d\right|\int_a^b f(t)dt$

**Case 1**:

If $d<\frac{a+b}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{d-a}>\frac{2}{b-a}$

Thus,$\left|f'(c)\right|\geq\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b f(t)dt\frac{1}{(b-d)} \left| \frac{a+b}{2}-d\right|\geq\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b f(t)dt$

**Case 2**:

If $d>\frac{a+b}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{b-d}>\frac{2}{b-a}$

Thus,$\left|f'(c)\right|\geq\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b f(t)dt\frac{1}{(d-a)} \left| \frac{a+b}{2}-d\right|\geq\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b f(t)dt$

So,in either case, we get $\left|f'(c)\right|\geq\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b f(t)dt$

Comment: Well ... that's a very long proof. There is a simple picture that gives a much shorter proof, which works if $f$ is just differentiable on $(a,b).$

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: I posted a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,1],$ differentiable on $(0,1),$ and $f(0)=0=f(1).$ Then there exists $c\in (0,1)$ such that $|f'(c)| \ge 4\int_0^1 f.$

Proof: If $\int_0^1f \le 0,$ there's nothing to show. So WLOG, $\int_0^1f = 1.$ (We can always multiply by a constant.) Connect the points $(0,0), (1/2,2), (1,0)$ with line segments, and let $t(x)$ be the resulting "triangular" function. (Good to draw a picture.) We must have $f(x_0) \ge t(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in (0,1).$ If not, then $f<t$ on this interval, hence

$$\int_0^1 f < \int_0^1 t = 1,$$

contradiction. Suppose $x_0\in (0,1/2].$ Then

$$\frac{f(x_0)-f(0}{x_0}\ge \frac{t(x_0)-t(0)}{x}=4.$$

By the MVT, the quotient on the left is $f'(c)$ for some $c\in (0,1/2)$ and we have the desired conclusion. A similar argument works if $x_0 \in [1/2,1).$

This result can be transferred to any $[a,b]$ with a linear change of variables to give the general result in the OP.